# Assign div from a website to a string

Tags: c#, html, string, web, html-agility-pack

```
                string locationName = Console.ReadLine();
                string url = "https://www.google.com/#q=latitude+and+longitude+" + locationName;

                HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
                HtmlNode rateNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='_XWk']");
                string res = rateNode.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine(res);
```

I am using the code above to get a certain location from google and copy the textbox displaying the latitude and longitude into the string res. Every time when I run the code I receive a nullReferenceException.

And how can I split the string into two strings with the coordinates only?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFfVP.jpg

`String res = "34.0522° N, 118.2437° W"` into `String res1 = "34.0522"` and `String res2 = "118.2437"`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Map Geocoding API. This API will send you a Json file.
Like this with newtonsoft Json library:

```
    String fileName = "LosAngeles";
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + fileName);
    WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        String json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        String lat = (string)jsonObject["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
        String lng = (string)jsonObject["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
        Console.WriteLine(lat + " : " + lng);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard because the content you are looking for is not in the HTML code of the link : https://www.google.com/#q=latitude+and+longitude+Paris

It's look like it's ajax injected en encoded from : https://www.google.com/search?q=latitude+and+longitude+paris&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&cad=b&fp=1&biw=1920&bih=677&dpr=1&tch=1&ech=1&psi=

```
\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22_XWk\\x22\\x3e48.8566\\xb0 N, 2.3522\\xb0 E\\x3c\/div\\x3e
```

A better way to get longitude and latitude for a city is to use the Google Map API :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris

Answer (score 0):

an easy way is to install library from NuGet or write in Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package GoogleMaps.LocationServices
```

after the package is installed you can get lat and log really easily because of using its built in functions

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string locationName = Console.ReadLine();

            var location = new GoogleLocationService();
            var point = location.GetLatLongFromAddress(locationName);

            Console.WriteLine(point.Latitude);
            Console.WriteLine(point.Longitude);
            Console.Read();

        }
```